# Box.com API 2 - search from website & present results from folder

Tags: php, forms, api, search, box-api

Quick question... (for a PHP intranet I am creating).

Is it possible to search documents in a Box.com account using their API 2???

Ideally I'd like to:

1. Search Box.com from within the intranet (a port is open to the outside world).
2. Present the results from a Box.com folder, as document titles that are links to download the document.

Any hint's or even just a link or 2 that 'totally' confirms this is possible would be really appreciated - as I have been hearing conflicting answers that this is & isn't possible.

Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to search a Box.com account through the API. See the documentation at http://developers.box.com/docs/#search

However, I don't think you can restrict the search to a single folder at present: you have to be logged in to Box to do the search and the only documented options are the search term and some control over how many results are returned. The documentation does say they will add filters but if you can filter results right now there's nothing in the documentation about it.